# Automatically route answers from question asker to page urging them to update original question

Tags: bug, status-completed

I have noticed that many inexperienced SO users tend to reply to answers by creating an answer rather than via a comment or an update to their original question. The problems this causes are:

1. The new "answer" will not make sense if it is re-ordered away from the answer it is responding to.
2. Even if order is maintained readers then have to piece together a disjointed set of answer/response posts which can get confusing.
3. Genuine answers get less screen estate.

This happens a lot and currently relies on flagging and editing by the community to resolve which generates a lot of overhead.

I suggest that if a user answers their own question they should be re-directed to a page which asks "are you sure this is the solution to your question?", and if not then prompts them to either comment on another answer or to append to/clarify their original question.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would help, after all, the answer button is already labeled that way. If they've failed to read the button, they'll fail to read the page.

Comment: They are already asked if they want to answer their own question. Try posting an answer to this question yourself.

Comment: Chris, I just posted an answer to this question and it didn't warn me at all.

Comment: That's odd - it used to. It seems like you've uncovered a bug.

Comment: @ChrisF, that's indeed odd. The answer box is pre-expanded for my own questions too now. It used to be just a button, which would then [show a warning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101067/answer-your-own-question-bug-with-chrome-and-probably-other-browsers). Must be a bug?

Comment: @Arjan For non-Meta questions, too?

Comment: I just tried to add another answer and I got the box saying "are you sure etc etc" so currently you get one answer before it starts to warn you

Comment: Yes, @Tim, no more button, and I guess no more "Are you sure you want to answer your own question?" either.

Comment: @Hugh, that's a different warning, saying something like "Are you sure you want to add ANOTHER answer?", and explaining about editing, right?

Comment: @Arjan yes that is the case

Comment: Related: the original behavior in [Limiting Self-Answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6593/limiting-self-answers/36436#36436).

Comment: Side note: Users with < 100 reputation are also supposed to be [prevented from self-answering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186) for 8 hours after posting.

Comment: @Tim: I wonder if that also applies to the nag message as well.  We all have over 100 so perhaps that's why we don't see it?

Comment: @JeffMercado - it used to nag regardless of your reputation. I've seen it when answering my own questions in the past.

Comment: @Chris: Yeah I know it used to do that but it obviously isn't the case right now.  I'm wondering if people who actually have less than 100 are actually seeing this message.  Otherwise it's a serious problem and might explain the explosion in flaggings of self-non-answers by newer users.

Comment: @ChrisF et al, indeed Jeff [has confirmed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6593/limiting-self-answers/36436#36436) this is a bug. Now, Hugh, when that warning is back, does your question still stand?

Comment: @Arjan, I still kind of think it't not enough. People are obviously ignoring the message. However, it may well explain why there are so many instances of this happening.

Comment: So you think that the page you're proposing (which, if I understand correctly, shows the same information, though maybe in a different manner) would not be ignored? I guess the same folks are also ignoring [the How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) that they [are forced to read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/how-does-stack-overflow-attempt-to-prevent-low-quality-questions-and-answers), well, are forced to click through.

Comment: Yeah maybe you're right. However I can kind of get into their heads abit. This page would prompt them towards a more acceptable form of response and make it easier for them. Maybe even creating an UPDATE header in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to my own question

Comment: This did not warn me that I was answering my own question

Comment: can you prove it? :-)

Comment: Actually you'll just have to trust me on this

Answer (score 10):

Indeed we broke

[Limiting Self-Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6593/limiting-self-answers/36436#36436)

so a fix is rolling out ASAP. Sorry about that.