# How do I update my question without getting banned?

Tags: support, asking-questions, low-quality-posts

I just tried to ask a question on this site for the first time ever. I got an answer that did not work and every time I tried to update the thread with my progress as I continued to search for a solution , and every update to the question got deleted. Then I was informed that answers were no longer being accepted from my account. How the hell is anyone supposed to work out a problem when they cannot post updates that include their progress?

Comment: If you have more information, you don't "update a thread," you "edit your question." All of the Stack Exchange sites are about questions and answers: they are *not* forums.

Comment: Did anyone tell you not to post updates-as-answers but to edit the question? If you didn't get a warning, and it was your first time using this site, I'm surprised you got banned.

Answer (score 17):

If you are posting updates then you should do that by editing the question. I'm guessing that you were adding answers (since there are only two edits to the question, neither of them made by you), which is why they were getting deleted: answers should really be *answers*, not updates.

Just click the 'edit' link underneath your question and you can update it.

Comment: +1 This is very likely what happened.

Comment: Initially I also didn't like this idea because I was so used to the "forum thread" mentality. Later I realise this was actually very good as it cuts a lot of crap and forces askers to get right to the point with their questions -- Exactly what an Q&A needs.

Comment: Yeah, and I should also point out that in order to answer your own question, you need to accept a JavaScript `alert()` box that explicitly states "If you need to add details to your question, use the edit link under your question."

Comment: @GeorgeEdison There was a bug yesterday that [broke the self-answer limitation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107170/automatically-route-answers-from-question-asker-to-page-urging-them-to-update-ori) (now fixed). The OP may not have seen that box, depending at what time he tried posting his updates.